# What is meaning by [Object, Object] error JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, dom-events

I have debugged my code for almost 2 hours as well as try to solve it by using this site [Object](https://medium.com/better-programming/what-is-object-object-in-javascript-object-prototype-tostring-1db888c695a4) but it does work. It seems there is an issue with the Controller model. The following is snapped from the code

```
    var budgetController = (function () {
    var number = 23;


})();

var UiController = (function () {
    // get the html  input (read the data )
    // you can return whather var by var or retuen one object that has all the HTML compenents 
    var DOMStrings = {
        inputType: '.add__type',
        inputDesc: '.add__description',
        inputValue: '.add__value',
        inputBtn: '.add__btn'
    };

    return {
        getInput: function () {
            return {
                type: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputType).value, // Will be either inc or exp
                description: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputDesc).value,
                value: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputValue).value
            };
        },
        getDOMStrings: function () {
            return DOMStrings;
        }
    };


})();


var Controller = (function (budgetCtr, UICtrl) {
    // Immediately Invoked Function Expression

    var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMStrings();
    var CtrAddItem = function () {
        // pass everthing to here 
        var output = UICtrl.getInput();
        console.info("Data  " + output);

    }
    document.querySelector('.add__btn').addEventListener('click', CtrAddItem);

    document.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {

        if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
            CtrAddItem();
        }
    });



})(budgetController, UiController);
```

The [Object , Object] appeared whenever I console log the output on the controller model

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you concat a string and an object using `+` the toString-method is called on the object (which by default just returns `[object Object]`). You should pass the object as the second argument instead:

`console.info("Data", output);`